# As I can create with username profile page Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, user-profile

I am unable to find accurate information to what I want, so my second choice is to ask.

So, I want to know how to create a user `profile` from scratch and with your `username` replacing the `ID`.

Example: `http://example.com/profile/{username}`
In this case I have no problems with usernames, as are those working on a game server and they can not contain spaces or unusual characters.

I have done something, but I think it is wrong, even though I do not have any error on my website.

Notes:
My Devise Model: Player/s

Schema of Players

```
    create_table "players", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "email",                  default: "",    null: false
    t.string   "encrypted_password",     default: "",    null: false
    t.string   "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer  "sign_in_count",          default: 0,     null: false
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.string   "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.string   "last_sign_in_ip"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.boolean  "admin",                  default: false
    t.integer  "role_id"
    t.string   "nick"
    t.string   "username"
  end
```

Variables "admin and role_id" are for charges will have on the web. I think this is not relevant to the subject.

Looked at other tutorials, but I have no more special things to add to my code.

My Controllers:
 - registrations_controller.rb

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  protected

  def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
    new_path(resource)
  end
end
```

- profile_controller.rb

  ```
      class ProfileController < ApplicationController
      def members
      end

      def myProfile
          @attributes = Profile.attribute_names - %w(id player_id created_at updated_at)
      end

      def new
          @profile = current_player.build_profile
      end

      def create
          @profile = current_player.build_profile(params[:profile].permit( :nick))
      end
  ```

  end

My Models:
 - player.rb

```
class Player < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :email, :presence => true, :email => true

  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
  :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
  belongs_to :role
  before_create :set_default_role

  has_one :profile

  private
  def set_default_role
    self.role ||= Role.find_by_name('registered')
  end
end
```

- profile.rb

  class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :players
  end

And in my view, have the controller profiles with:
myProfile => Only the profile of the user
profiles that is the global view of the profiles

route.rb

```
get 'profile/:id' => 'profile#perfiles'

  resources :profile, only: [:edit]

  map.resources :players, :has_one => :profile
  map.resources :profiles
```

I hope I'm not asking for much, but hey, it's a question that I have and worth a try.

Thanks in advance, if anything is missing tell me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe what you're looking to do is override the named route parameter. See this rails guide for more details: http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html (section 4.10).

Basically, you'll want to just add the `param: :username` to your routes file:

```
resources :profile, only: [:edit], param: :username
```

Which will make your route look something like:

```
profile GET  /profile/:username(.:format)  profile#show
```

And in your controller:

```
@profile = Profile.find_by(username: params[:username])
```

Hope that helps!